# Delete TWO TABLES entries WITH SINGLE Query

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, sqlite

I am trying to delete TWO TABLES entries WITH SINGLE Query in my sqlite database on my iPhone app, but am getting a weird error.

```
DELETE Sec1Opr_Equipment.*, Sec2Opr_Equipment.* FROM 
Sec1Opr_Equipment INNER JOIN Sec2Opr_Equipment ON Sec1Opr_Equipment.ID = Sec2Opr_Equipment.ID 
WHERE Sec1Opr_Equipment.ID='1'
```

And also Try

```
DELETE Sec1Opr_Equipment,Sec2Opr_Equipment
FROM Sec1Opr_Equipment
LEFT JOIN Sec2Opr_Equipment
ON Sec1Opr_Equipment.ID = Sec2Opr_Equipment.ID
WHERE Sec2Opr_Equipment.ID='1'
```

Plz any one help me..
thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to include the error message.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, in SQLite the delete statement can only delete records from a single table without any joins. You can use subqueries in your WHERE clause though:

```
DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tbl2 WHERE ...)
```